# Hyperledger Composer REST API appears a "transactionId": "string"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have this issue when connecting the browser to the REST API in Hyperledger Composer. It appears a new field when trying to post a tarnsaction, called "transactionId": "string" and "timestamp2:

```
{
  "$class": "org.cryptolab.economiassociales.AnadirNodo",
  "idNodo": "string",
  "nombre": "string",
  "localizacion": "string",
  "delegada": "string",
  "numeroMiembrosParticipantes": 0,
  "transactionId": "string",
  "timestamp": "2019-03-18T15:55:40.857Z"
}
```

trying to fill the transactionId string, the transaction fails with 422 error code:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 422,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "The `AnadirNodo` instance is not valid. Details: `transactionId` can't be set (value: \"s1\").",
    "details": {
      "context": "AnadirNodo",
      "codes": {
        "transactionId": [
          "absence"
        ]
      },
      "messages": {
        "transactionId": [
          "can't be set"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stack": "ValidationError: The `AnadirNodo` instance is not valid. Details: `transactionId` can't be set (value: \"s1\").\n    at /home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:400:12\n    at AnadirNodo.<anonymous> (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:578:11)\n    at AnadirNodo.next (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:93:12)\n    at AnadirNodo.<anonymous> (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:575:23)\n    at AnadirNodo.trigger (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:83:12)\n    at AnadirNodo.Validatable.isValid (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:541:8)\n    at /home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:396:9\n    at doNotify (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at doNotify (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:155:49)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:178:5)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:153:8)\n    at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/hyperledger/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:176:15)"
  }
}
```

It seems similar to this topic:
[transactionId when submitting a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894071/transactionid-when-submitting-a-transaction#42924625)

What can I do? it is frustrating...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618081/error-executing-hyperledger-fabric-code-on-localhost3000-through-rest-trans) **Answer**. Post your transaction as follows:

```
{
  "$class": "org.cryptolab.economiassociales.AnadirNodo",
  "idNodo": "string",
  "nombre": "string",
  "localizacion": "string",
  "delegada": "string",
  "numeroMiembrosParticipantes": 0
}
```

Hope it will help you :)